# Error installing MeiliSearch on Lumen: Curl (35) schannel: InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012)

Tags: laravel, lumen, meilisearch

I'm trying to install Meilisearch on my Lumen project.
I ran this command

```
curl -L https://install.meilisearch.com | sh
```

then i get this error:

```
curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.
```

[image: image of console output]

"php": "^7.3|^8.0",
"laravel/lumen-framework": "^8.3.1",

I also tried to add -k before https to disables cert validation, but it didn't work.
I know that Lumen is deprecated, but I this is not my project so I can't use Laravel instead of Lumen.

I have been stuck in this installing process for several days, if anyone know how to install Meilisearch to Lumen project, that would save my life.

Thank you so much.